# change from colored to grayscale in image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, grayscale

today I treid a python filtering code that supposes to increase the noise in the image(de-noising) for a gray-scale image(medical image) and it's for a skull, the problem is i keep getting colored pixels, i mean the noise increased in terms of colored image, not in grayscale so please help me to make the code filter in gray-scale mode, extra details :

the code :

[enter link description to see the filter code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-noise-function-in-wand/)

[**original image :**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ccC1.jpg)

[the de-noised image after applying noise filter :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iqr4.jpg)

you can see the problem clearly that when i zoom into the picture i can see the colored pixels, while it supposes to be a gray-scale form

colored pixels in the filtered image :

[partial zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0mOB.png)

[full zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0sdl.png)

so please guess does anybody knows how to edit that code so that it can increase the noise in form of grayscale mode.

Comment: Looks like, for a given pixel, it adds three different numbers to the three color channels.

Comment: @MarkLavin yeah i know , but am wondering how to change it to a gray-scale mode , where pixels are only black-white

Comment: add your code to the question, so the code itself is in the question.

Comment: The image is indeed not grayscale. You have two options: force loading the file as grayscale, or convert to grayscale after loading.

Comment: Note that de-noising is removal of noise, not addition of noise !

Comment: @YvesDaoust 
ohh yeh
sorry my fult

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz
thanks for the advise 
actually am new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input image is a 3-channel JPEG. Make it greyscale (1 channel) before applying noise then it won't be able to treat the channels differently because there will only be one.

```
img.transform_colorspace('gray')
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked  thanks
but a little question: does this reduce the original image resolution?

Comment: No, you can print `img.shape` before and afterwards to convince yourself.